# beautifulsoup in python returning none when "div" tag and class name is there

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB&.tsrc=fin-srch')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
price=soup.find('div', class_='D(ib) Mend(20px)')
print(price)
```

[image]

Comment: That element may be being loaded by JavaScript after the page loads. You may need to use a library capable of running JavaScript to get that element.

Comment: https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-use-the-yahoo-finance-api/